# Importing multiprocessing gives importerror

Tags: python

when I try to run the following code...

```
from hashlib import new
from multiprocessing.connection import wait
```

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./callerID.py", line 3, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.connection import wait
ImportError: cannot import name wait
```

If I run `pip install multiprocessing` I get

```c
    In file included from Modules/_multiprocessing/multiprocessing.c:9:0:
    Modules/_multiprocessing/multiprocessing.h:6:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-tmZJGD/multiprocessing/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-K20qjG-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tmZJGD/multiprocessing/
```

What can I do to fix this error.
The host is running on Freepbx.

Comment: You need at least Python 3.3+, whereas you're trying to run this code with Python 2.x, which doesn't have `multiprocessing.connection.wait`.  The `multiprocessing` module off PyPI does not have this function either - it's an old backport of `multiprocessing` for older Python versions. If you're running the FreePBX distro, which is based on CentOS7, do you have the ability to install `python34`?

Comment: @wkl I cant install any modules because I cant install pip3, a slue of errors over 1000 lines.

Comment: @LandynJ Do you have Python 3 already installed?

Comment: @CrazyChucky yes

Comment: @LandynJ In that case what if you run this script with `python3 callerID.py` or however you're running it?

Comment: It wont work, because Pyst2 is for python 2 (thats the package requiring wait by the way)

Comment: In that case...you might be out of luck unless you can either install `pyst2` into your Python 3.x installation, or you modify your code to not require new `multiprocessing` functionality. I'm seeing that `pyst2` supports up to Python 3.4 (and probably newer), according to PyPI. If you're trying to change the code, a sorta-substitute for `multiprocessing.connection.wait()` is `select.select()`

Comment: In that case, it's a bug in pyst2. It's claiming to be Python 2 compatible, and installing on Python 2, but trying to use functionality that Python 2 doesn't have. Unfortunately the package is no longer maintained, so there's no way to even report the bug.

Comment: It seems to also work in python3, but I cant install pip3 on the system.

Comment: Yeah, I expect that the developer forgot to check Python 2 compatibility as they added the dependence on Python 3 (or else forgot to remove Python 2 in the compatibility list). Python 2 is long past its end-of-life and not usually actively developed for these days. You might have better luck asking here about trying to get pip3 working.